# Typescript using object spread to satisfy a generic union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given a union type with common fields `type` and `fedBy`. I want to write a function that takes in an `Animal` as the type and a second argument with the params unique to that animal. I can get the signature and inference working, but doing something wrong in how to return the result.

```js
type FeedAnimalParams =
  | {
      type: 'Dog'
      fedBy: string
      bowl: true
    }
  | {
      type: 'Cat'
      fedBy: string
      fish: string
    }
  | {
      type: 'Bird'
      fedBy: string
      seed: string
    }
```

I'm inferring a literal type, pulling out the `type` property

```js
type Animal = FeedAnimalParams['type']
//type Animal = "Dog" | "Cat" | "Bird"
```

I'm pulling the unique fields required for each animal using a generic.

```js
type UniqueAnimalParams<T extends Animal> = Omit<Extract<FeedAnimalParams, { type: T }>, 'type' | 'fedBy'>

type FeedResult<T> = {
  message: string
  result: T
}
```

Here's the function I'm trying to write

```js
function feed<T extends Animal>(
  byWhom: string,
  animalType: T,
  params: UniqueAnimalParams<T>,
): FeedResult<FeedAnimalParams> {
  return {
    message: `Fed by ${byWhom}`,
    result: { //compile error here
      type: animalType,
      fedBy: byWhom,
      ...params,
    },
  }
}


//other lib
function CantChangeSignature(input:FeedAnimalParams){
  console.log(input)
}
```

I get the intellisense when calling the function, so inference appears to be working but the function doesn't compile.

```js
feed('Colin', 'Bird', {
  seed: 'Sunflower',
})

feed('Joe', 'Dog', {
  bowl: true,
})
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYhEBMCCA7AlgWwIYBsAKWATlhgM5QC8AUFFAD5QDeNtrokAXFAOQAiA9gHNuLVlABmiAEIgupYITQpBo1gCN+AdxxcFAVwiqAviwbMxtdhC7cAwlmAiLE6bKjzFy1bXFpSACzkFJRUxE1ozbygrGyk0QgQnC0kEGSDPUItSeAR0kOMqKisoVExcSlgc0ux8IhJSAG1uK24AXULigFV0AEcDatwCYjIAHgAVKAgAD2AIFARyAZwAPgqAeQw0YBGAURniAGNtuEQlofqAGiZo8GsoCaNlq+bb7noeFJluZY7bysQAEoQUh6HDbMarChMFgYYGkLCCO4efK0QjA0HALhjKgmKiSRAACjs-BwSm4zziCXJ0No2UQNgAynoUOIcFoIIRyTiAJSFfEIIkAKX4EGpfCE1PMUA02l0hAMFx5fOZRzQ-BQLkQ40mMzmCxK6BqywJLDUIAA6v5+Bg8spFbQsIbcGNblj7VAwHUyFxumg+hAzl7SOMnlRuVwTgggSCwSNI4HhqRVlK0cA9IQNVLaLDSPDEVwAAZwBDSkBQAAkjDNlutRgL7tR6LBXCzbFdUEdZRwLsgDdYnzc1atGD7tAAdBPPYm+0Z3SYTEA)

Edit:1
Trying to avoid changing the return type signature since I need to pass it into another function I can't change.

```js
FeedResult<FeedAnimalParams>

//also tried this as the return type

FeedResult<Extract<FeedAnimalParams, {type:T}>>
```

[Updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYhEBMCCA7AlgWwIYBsAKWATlhgM5QC8AUFFAD5QDeNtrokAXFAOQAiA9gHNuLVlABmiAEIgupYITQpBo1gCN+AdxxcFAVwiqAviwbMxtdhC7cAwlmAiLE6bKjzFy1bXFpSACzkFJRUxE1ozbygrGyk0QgQnC0kEGSDPUItSeAR0kOMqKisoVExcSlgc0ux8IhJSAG1uK24AXULigFV0AEcDatwCYjIAHgAVKAgAD2AIFARyAZwAPgqAeQw0YBGAURniAGNtuEQlofqAGiZo8GsoCaNlq+bb7noeFJluZY7bysQAEoQUh6HDbMarChMFgYYGkLCCO4efK0QjA0HALhjKgmKiSRAACjs-BwSm4zziCXJ0No2UQNgAynoUOIcFoIIRyTiAJSFA78FDyKAIBxYCr4hBEgBS-Ag1L4Qmp5igGm0ukIBguPMK9hQwFs-iwyggDLQghQDj0aIJIuAWAAdGiQWDuQBuQp45lHNAClyIcaTGZzBYldA1ZYElhqEAAdX8-AweWUWtoRrKODGtyxKagYDqZC43TQfQgZ3zpHGTyo3K4-wQQOdxyqYcG5dWtEYUAA9F2oLhSPxoopELQTvX0WDdvssEcRmOy8NSFdGDExo92zSoGjgFaUJvaLDSPDEVwAAZwBAqkBQAAkjGjcYTRlPOdRE8x+7YWb7LYzt1frCfG4D7xhgAG0PakF5ouAFGDmJi4j2-DAP4HJQKSaieig3q+rq+qGsaprmpa1pKGAeiYvOv7nGQ3LKvygokhA9psoIBJkRRvJGEAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to relate to the return type to the generic otherwise TS can't make the return value to be specific to the passed `animalType` so it thinks it's all of them all at once.

```
function feed<T extends Animal>(
  byWhom: string,
  animalType: T,
  params: UniqueAnimalParams<T>,
): FeedResult<UniqueAnimalParams<T> & {type: T, fedBy: string}>   {
  return {
    message: `Fed by ${byWhom}`,
    result: {
      type: animalType,
      fedBy: byWhom,
      ...params,
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: That's close, but I'm trying to avoid messing with the type of the return value. In my real world example it's another function I'm calling in a library. Updated playground link.

Comment: Gotcha. You have limited choices here. The most basic is either adding the return type, or changing the argument types, but the latter would lead to losing clever Intellisense on the arguments. There are some nicer options though, and I think these are the tools you should reach for. (1) You could use module declarations to change the overly restrictive library types such that they are compatible, or (2) create a wrapper function of `feed` which calls the base `feed` but with looser types, and potentially casting.